# trying to show currency based on user's locale

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

What's the best solution to show currency based on the user's locale? I know there's `toLocaleString('en-US', {style})` but is there away to detect the location of the user instead then show their currency?

Don't think `window.navigator.languages` will be a good solution? though this gives array of languages `['en-US', 'en', 'something', 'en-GB']`, not sure if this is always gonna be the same if the user somewhere else.

Also I don't think multiple `toLocalString()` works, thought it could be a solution but seems like it only takes one locale.

```
var number = 100;
number.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}, 'en-GB', {style: 'currency',currency: 'GBP'})
```

Comment: How about using the geolocation object in html5? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Comment: yeah I thought of it but that will ask the user to use their current location, I want something that automatically detects the user's locale.